# How to call interviewer when I don't know company culture?

Tags: interviewing, sri-lanka

Background: Software Engineering, Sri Lanka

Different software companies in Sri Lanka use different culture to call senior developers, managers, etc.

Eg: Some companies use Sir, some companies use Mr. Name, Some companies use just name.

Manager or senior developers are in almost all interview panel I have faced. But I don't know how to call them(Sir, just name or Mr. name) during interview. So most of the time I just say "You, your, etc".

So, what is the best way to call them?

Comment: Can anyone please tell me that what is wrong with my question? It received two downvotes and no upvotes.

Answer (score 1):

Call by **Mr/Ms. Last Name**. If they prefer any other way, they will indicate in first or second meeting.

Also check (if you can) if they have a PhD in which case you may need to address them as **Dr. Last Name**.

Answer (score 0):

You can ask them.

State that in your experience, you've addressed people one of three ways to show proper respect, and as you don't know which way they prefer, would they like to be addressed like (first option), (second option), or (third option).

This shows your awareness of different expectations, and your willingness to adapt to the needs / desires of others to facilitate communication.  Often these traits are considered valuable.